# Spring config server read proterties from local machine if fetch data from git repositories failed

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-properties, spring-boot-configuration

I am new for **spring config server**. I want to implement **spring config server** from my application where my config server **fetch properties details** from **git repositories** but in case of my **git server are not able to respond**, how can I read properties from my local machine?

**Note: I want to read properties from my local machine only in case my git server are not able to respond.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following configurations by repository.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/your-repository/config-repo
          repos:
            local:
              pattern: local*
              uri: file:/home/your-directory/config-repo
```

1. **local** repository will match all application names beginning with local in all profiles.
2. If was not matched your application names beginning with **local** in all profiles then by default URI **spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri** value will be replaced.

Here is documentation about it [config-server-multiple-repositories](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories%22config-server-multiple-repositories%22).